# Is there a Listview column editor for runtime use?

Tags: delphi, listview

Is there an inbuilt or available component in Delphi that can be used for a listview in determining what columns and order they are shown, as per image?

[image: ShowColumns]

Happy to do my own... but not if this is already there

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

The Windows `ListView` common control does not have a corresponding `ListViewColumnSelector` control.

i've had to create my own for Mike Lischke's `Virtual TreeView` control.